# Why is my NSDate null? Need help parsing django datetimefield string

Tags: objective-c, django, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm receiving datetime.datetime strings from a django REST api and I'm having trouble converting them into NSDate objects.  I've written this block to parse a sample datetime string (`dateString`)

```
NSString *dateString =@"2014-05-31-T20:11:21.019Z";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'-T'HH':'mm'.'sss'Z'"];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date string: %@", dateString);
NSLog(@"date object: %@", date);
NSLog(@"date string: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

The console output looks like this:

```
date string: 2014-05-31-T20:11:21.019Z
date object: (null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Format is wrong. You have not accounted for seconds component. Please check using below.

```
NSString *dateString =@"2014-05-31-T20:11:21.019Z";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'-T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSSZ"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date string: %@", dateString);
NSLog(@"date object: %@", date);
```

Comment: No need for any of the quotes in the format except around the `T`. Just use `@"yyyy-MM-dd-'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

Comment: Both of these work, so thank you.  As a note to anyone else who may stumble across this: another problem was that my `SetDateStyle` and `SetTimeStyle` lines needed to be after the declaration `NSDate *date`

Comment: @MoeJan You should never use both `setDateFormat:` and the "setXXXXstyle:` methods on the same date formatter. Use one or the other. If you want to convert a date string from one format to another, use two date formatters, one for each format.